# SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import

Tags: angular, sass, version

I upgrade the Angular application version from 14 to 15 and I m getting  **SassError.**

package.json

"@angular/material": "15.0.0",

"@angular/material-experimental": "15.2.0",

I have **stylePreprocessorOptions** in angular.json file.

`"stylePreprocessorOptions": { "includePaths": [ "src", "./node_modules" ] }`

```
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │ @use '@angular/material-experimental/mdc-core/theming/all-theme' as mdc-theme;
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  apps/sanalmarket-frontend-project/src/assets/styles/themes/_default.scss 2:1  @use
  apps/sanalmarket-frontend-project/src/assets/styles/main.scss 17:1            root stylesheet
```

`_default.scss` file imports

```
@use '@angular/material-experimental/mdc-core/theming/all-theme' as mdc-theme;
@use '@angular/material-experimental/mdc-core/typography/all-typography' as mdc-typography;
```

I solved the dependecy problems but still I m getting error.